# How to fix wrong date format issue in prod environment and dev environment in angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, date-format

I'm trying to write an Angular pipe to format dates. The implementation works correctly in the development environment but in production, it shows values in an incorrect format. I'm unsure what causes this issue.

Below is the code that I have tried so far.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string) {
    super(_locale);
  }

  transform(value: any): any {
    const currentDate = new Date(value);
    const format = `${environment.appDateFormat}`;

    if (currentDate.getFullYear() === 1900) {
      return '';
    }
    
    return super.transform(value, format);
  }
}
```

This returns

- in `dev`  environment:   `2020/10/09`
- in `prod` environment:  `2020/09/10`

Comment: do not just down grade please . if more infor need please comment

Comment: It seems your locale is different in dev and prod. What is the content of `appDateFormat` variable?